# list.append takes exactly one argument (gived 2)

Tags: python, list

I am doing a little game, I am new at programming so i wanna start somehow so i have got a game and i want to add animation when you are walking. But i am not able to use more images it is showing me this error. and if you will be open to give me advise for using animation it would be great. I have this (in the important section):

```
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images = []
        for i in range(1, 5):
            mich = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', r'C:/users/filip/documents/rozsireni/Jumpi'
                                                            r'ng 6.png')).convert()
            mich2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', r'C:/users/filip/documents/rozsireni/Jumpi'
                                                             r'ng 7.png')).convert()
            mich = pygame.transform.scale(mich, (100, 100))
            mich2 = pygame.transform.scale(mich2, (100, 100))
            mich.convert_alpha()
            mich.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
            mich2.convert_alpha()
            mich2.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
            self.images.append(mich, mich2)
            self.image = self.images[0]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


player = Player()
player.rect.x = 300
player.rect.y = 300
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

```py
self.images.append(mich, mich2)
```

You can only append one element at a time, use `list.extend([...])` instead if you want to append several elements.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure how to do the walking cycle exactly (I can do it, but extremly complicated way), but this helps a little, so thanks. Filip Dvorak

Comment: The first thing I can recommend looking at your code is loading  all the images and applying any transform only once rather than every cycle of your for loop.

Comment: I had that but then i thought that it would be better to just load it with defining the function, but probably you are right, i should get i back thanks.

Comment: But actualy still not have it working properly but probably gonna figure it out pretty soon, hope.